# Porque al haer zoom se disminuyen de tamaño todos los elementos más no la rana

Tags: html5, css3

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

.globalWrapper {
    width: 1024px;
    background-color: #DFAFF9;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.wrapperMain{
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #FEF9CF;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
#backgroundHeader img{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.textoImagen{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}


#headerImage>img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    right: 150px;
    background-image: url("imgs/header.png");
    width:20%;
    height:150px;
}

#title1{
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 10%;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#title2{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 10%;
    color: orange;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#bar {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #E49C32 !important;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

#lorem {
    color: #432366;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 10%;
    margin-left:5px;
}

#ranaImage>img{
        width: 45%;
}

#ranaImage img{
        width: 100%;
}


#parrafo{
     width: 50%;
     float: right;
     text-align: justify;
}

.myButton {
    background-color:#44c767;
    -moz-border-radius:28px;
    -webkit-border-radius:28px;
    border-radius:28px;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:16px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.colorBackground{
        background-color:#44c767;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 1%;
}


table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: solid;
}

footer {
    width: 96%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #B5B2A0;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; 
}

#textFooter{
    color: #4286f4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="globalWrapper">
    <div class="wrapperMain">
        <section id="header">
            <header>
             <div id="backgroundHeader">
                    <img src="imgs/fondo.png" alt="fondo encabezado" title="fondo encabezado"/>
                    <div id="headerImage">
                        <img src="imgs/header.png" alt="loros" title="loros"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="textoImagen">
                        <h1 id="title1">Carlos Acevedo</h1>
                        <h2 id="title2">Tecnólogo ADSI</h2>
                    </div>
             </div>
          </header>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div id="bar">
            </div>
            <div>
                    <p id="lorem">Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="box" id="ranaImage">
                    <img src="imgs/rana.jpg" alt="rana" title="rana"/>
            </div>
                <div class="box" id="parrafo">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="myButton">Perspiciate</a>
                </div>  
        </section>
        <section>
            <article class="box">
                 <table>
                      <tr class="colorBackground">
                        <th>Header</th>
                        <th>Header</th>
                        <th>Header</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>   
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table> 
            </article>
            <article class="box">
               <form method="POST" action="">
                <p>
                    Autenticar
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" value="" required="6" placeholder="usuario" title="Usuario"/>
                        <br/>
                        <input name="usuario" type="radio" value="u" checked />Usuario<br/>
                        <input name="administrador" type="radio" value="a" />Administrador<br/>
                        <br/>           
                </p>    
                <div>
                        <a href="#" class="myButton">Log in</a>
                        <a href="#" class="myButton">Reset</a>
                </div>      
            </article>
        </section>
        <footer id="textFooter">
                Copyright © 2018 <strong>All Right Reserveds</strong>
        </footer>   
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Imagen]

Answer (score 0):

Hola al aplicar en tu `#headerImage>img` una altura en pixeles pues se va a redimensionar, prueba trabajando en porcentaje (%) y notarás la diferencia:

```
#headerImage>img{
   display: inline-block;
    top: 21px;
    right: 150px;
    background-image: url("imgs/header.png");
    width:20%;
    height:15%; /*cambia a un valor porcentual*/
}
```

Espero te ayude.

Saludos

Comment: @@Maximo Guando Quispe, hice el cambio propuesto, la rana sigue grande, desubico los loros y la letra del hederImage se reduce dentro del contenedor de la imagen cuando se le da zoom.